# Unable to add target to UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, target

I have a `UIButton` that I created programmatically. I have added a target to it, but it doesn't seem to be running properly. Here is my code (This is a custom class of `UIView`):

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    print("targets:")
    print(clickButton.allTargets())
    clickButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clickPicture), for: .touchUpInside)
    print("targets:")
    print(clickButton.allTargets())

}
```

This is what prints as a result:

[image]

As you can see, adding a target to my button does not make a difference. Here is the `clickPicture` function:

```
func clickPicture() {

    print("clickpicture")

}
```

Again, this does not print. Does anybody know how to fix this error? Thanks!

Edit:

Definition for `clickButton` (in my custom class):

```
var clickButton = UIButton()
```

Other properties defined in the `init`:

```
clickButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
clickButton.layer.cornerRadius = clickButton.frame.size.width / 2
clickButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white().cgColor
clickButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.5
clickButton.layer.backgroundColor = shadeColor.cgColor
clickButton.center.x = self.center.x
clickButton.center.y = self.frame.size.height - clickButton.frame.size.height// + 40
clickButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clickPicture), for: .touchUpInside)
self.addSubview(clickButton)
```

Comment: Please show us where `clickButton` is defined.

Comment: @appzYourLife I edited my question.

Comment: Please show me the full code. I cannot understand where this code is inside your class.

Comment: clickButton is publicly defined in the class. The rest is in my init. I do not want to post all of my code as it is quite a great amount.

Comment: So `clickButton` is a property?

Comment: Yes it is a property

Comment: Does your UIView (where you added your UIButton) accept TouchEvents? Your Code seems fine. Ill guess there should be a problem with your custom UIView.

Comment: @derdida it does accept TouchEvents as I have other buttons as well. Is it possible it is an Xcode 8/Swift 3 bug?

Comment: Can I see your init() method implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button was not on top of the custom view when I instantiated it. I changed its position, and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change this line

```
clickButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clickPicture), for: .touchUpInside)
```

to this

```
clickButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourClassName.clickPicture), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

And the method should be

```
func clickPicture() {

    print("clickpicture")

}
```

Comment: Not really. This makes only sense if you need your UIButton Object in your function.

Comment: Edited the answer. Check it now

Comment: Replace 'YourClassName' with the name of your class which contains 'clickPicture' method

Comment: This doesn't make any difference... Simply adding YourClassName instead of self doesn't change anything

Comment: @penatheboss, did you try it?

Comment: And did you swap `for` with `forControlEvents` ?